# How to support emoji as param value?

Tags: java, android, scribe, emoji

I am trying to send an android emoji UTF-8 encoded value as a param but is not working. For Oauth it is used Scribe The server is returning 401.
The code snippet is:

```
OAuthRequest testRequest = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, BASE_URI + "/path/testParam?testParam=%F0%9F%90%B1");
getService().signRequest(token, testRequest);
Response response = testRequest.send();
System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

If I put other values for testParam it is going through. Or if I don't sign the request. Does someone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by double encoding the param value.

Comment: hi bro, I need this help, can you show one example of the double encoding, and the string representation result of the double encoding. I facing the same problem right now